# Mouse and MacBook image appear at startup

Tags: macbook-pro

Mouse and MacBook image appear at startup! What could be the problem?

[image]

Comment: It appears to be telling you to turn on your Magic Mouse.  Do you have a Magic Mouse paired/connected?

Comment: I have a mouse but it’s not recognizing it